# Should I provide hi-res website images to mobile devices? What about minimizing download size?

Tags: image, responsive-design, responsive-images, srcset

With the newer phones offering up to x3 density rendering, I am tempted to serve up x3 hi-res images to them using the HTML element srcset. However, I am concerned about the added mobile data requirements from doing so.

Do you tend to reserve hi-res images to larger devices (e.g., laptops and desktops) that usually do not use mobile data? Or perhaps, compromise and provide up to x2 images, rather than x3?

I am trying to find the balance between providing mobile web pages that are as light as possible in size, minimizing data usage and maximizing speed, and providing nice, crisp images.

Thanks, Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's more up to x4 density now: https://www.mydevice.io/#compare-devices

There is unfortunately to simple way to prevent loading of huge images on small devices with really high density.

We should even be able to limit density to ~2.5dppx based on [this study](https://observablehq.com/@eeeps/visual-acuity-and-device-pixel-ratio):

> - DPR 2 is good enough for most people
> - DPR 3 only benefits a very lucky few

There are discussions about this in issues on the HTML standard:

- [Responsive images causes performance issues on high-resolution devices](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/4421)
- [Possibility to mark image candidate as high compressed](https://github.com/ResponsiveImagesCG/picture-element/issues/273)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful links to get me started! I would guess that newer phones, for example with x3 and greater, are likely to have more up-to-date browsers, which support the newer webp and avif image formats. Reserving larger, higher-res sizes images to webp and avif formats, while using smaller jpeg sizes as fallback, could be an important strategy in reducing mobile data usage when serving x2 and x3 images.

Comment: If you can provide AVIF (or at least WebP), the best would be to use it for all browsers supporting it, whatever the screen resolution. Using an image optimization solution (sometimes called "image CDN") is an easy way.